# Creating FaceTime link on website

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad

I've created a link to call someone using facetime using the spec provided on the [Apple dev site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html) as such:

```
<a href="facetime:user@example.com">Connect using FaceTime</a>
```

However, when i click the link in iOS Safari, it'll prompt the user if they want to call "user@example.com", but when you click the FaceTime link in the prompt, it simply opens the FaceTime app without passing the "user@example.com" address to make the call.

What am I doing wrong?

FYI: This is on an iOS iPad using 8.1.1.

Comment: Ever find an answer?  I'm struggling with the same thing - see this thread for details: [apple-facetime-url-scheme-not-initiating-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749122/apple-facetime-url-scheme-not-initiating-call)

Comment: Yes. It's a bug with iOS. I've reported it with Apple and they've currently fixed with the latest Beta of iOS. They just need to push this fix out.